# How to stop Dell notification on my computer?

Tags: prompt, popups, cleaning, factory-defaults

This annoying message comes up all the time. Even when I press "Do not remind me", it keeps coming. How can I get rid of it for good?[image]

Comment: I suggest that you delete Dell Backup and Recovery application if you don't use it.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall the "Dell Backup and Recovery" utility if you don't ever intend to use it.
If you do use it you will need to start the program itself with "Run as Administrator" and then disable the notifications from within the program.
On modern Windows versions the Popup you are getting never runs with admin-rights in the first place, so it can't properly save the setting.
(It is a design flaw that is a left-over of the old XP days when "everything runs always as admin" was the norm. It shouldn't need admin-right for saving such a setting.)